# Adding extras property to exported gltf .glb

Tags: python, gltf

The GLTF specification includes a top level extras property for application specific data.  How can I **inject my own top level extras property** data when calling the **bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf** method?

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0#reference-extras

Comment: The glTF exporter doesn't give a way to write to that.

Comment: Thanks @scurest!